# What happens if someone realizes that infinite Tsukuyomi is a dream, like Neo in The Matrix?

Tags: anime, naruto, manga

As we are shown in the anime and manga, all the people trapped in Infinite Tsukuyomi will become white Zetsu with the passage of time. How much time will it take to turn trapped people to white Zetsu?

What if someone realizes that it's a dream world before turning into white Zetsu? Will they ever be able to come out of that?

Comment: this question may be better for the manga SE, but i dont think anyone but naruto or sasuke could have had any awareness during the infinite tsukuyomi. I believe that was mentioned in the manga, though i really didnt care at that point since it had literally the worse ending ever and wasted almost 10 years of my life.

Comment: If it turns out like The Matrix, you get one good movie, and two boring ones.

Answer (score 2):

Jiray taught Naruto how to get out of genjutsu. During the battle between Naruto and Itachi, Naruto tries to get out of his genjutsu but it drained all of his chakra, this is level 3 genjutsu.

The Infinite Tsukiyomi is beyond any level of genjutsu, it is not easy to get out of it. Even if someone realizes that they are in Infinite Tsukiyomi nothing changes, the dream depends on an individual's will.

Comment: So since the illusion is constructed based on the victim's mind it could potentially make it appear that they escaped but are sti-*interrupted by Inception bwong*